# Small $p$ with $1-4A$ a square in $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true / known / easy to prove that for any integer $A>0$, there is an odd prime $p\le \sqrt A+1000$ such that $1-4A$ is a square (quadratic residue or $0$) modulo $p$?

Comment: The constant $1000$ seems like a contrived obstacle. What motivated that choice?

Comment: @quasi: This is not an obstacle in fact, having this $+1000$ helps to find $p$ and thus makes the problem a little bit easier (assuming that the answer is positive).

Comment: @quasi: anyway, I am interested in all variations: $+1000$, $-1000$, and pure $\sqrt{|A|}$.

Comment: Let $c$ be the constant term. For $c=0$, there are lots of counterexamples. If $c$ is in the interval $[0,34]$, then $A=41$ is a counterexample.

Comment: $p \ll (\log A)^2$ works under GRH, and $p \ll A^{1/4 + \varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ works unconditionally (that is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there are only finitely many $A$ for which you can't find a $p < A^{1/4 + \varepsilon}$. These arguments can be made effective with some pain; I suspect one could determine all $A$ for which $p < \sqrt{A}$  is not good enough and surelyprobably $p < \sqrt{A} + 1000$ is always fine. This relates to work of Linnik. For a precise reference see https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2014-142-06/S0002-9939-2014-12199-X/S0002-9939-2014-12199-X.pdf